# Why does Careers ask me to associate my account, when it shows it is associated?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

on the associate account tab, it asks me to associate my account.. but its already associated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal, the help text on the associate page is fixed.

The button itself (next to the account, on the same tab) should indicate the actual association status.